# How to suppress -Wno-protocol per file

Tags: ios, xcode, gcc, clang, gcc-warning

I have implementation of Objective-C Protocol which forward all protocol's methods to another target. Everething is fine except that compiler warns that this Class doesn implement protocol's method. I am trying suppress this warning using #pragma diagnostic:

```
//Header file
@protocol A
-(void)test;
@end

@interface AImpl : NSObject<A> {
    id<A> myItems;
}
@end

//Implementation file:
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic push

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wno-protocol"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wno-protocol"

@implementation AImpl
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation {
SEL selector = [invocation selector];

    if ([myItems respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    [invocation invokeWithTarget:myItems];
} else {
    [super forwardInvocation:invocation];
}
}
@end

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

But compiler warns that "Unknown warning group '-Wno-protocol'"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've 3 immediate approaches:

**1)** you can do this instead:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"
```

you specify the group to disable using the pragma, rather than the compiler flag to set/alter.

**2)** or you can correct the issue like so (assuming you are not declaring a root class):

```
@interface AImpl : NSObject<A>
{
  id<NSObject,A> myItems;
}
@end
```

**3)**  or you can specify the setting on a per-file basis in Xcode's *Project > Target > Build Phases > Compile Sources > Compiler Flags = "-Wno-protocol"*

I'd go with #2.

Comment: Thank you Justin, but unfortunately #2 doesn't work for me. compiler still warns about "Incomplete implementation"

Comment: i see - #2 would reduce only some of the warnings. you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"
@implementation ClassName
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

and only temporarily disables warning. But seemingly for all protocols for the entire class. What I'd really like is to disable the warning for just a single method of the protocol (it's implemented by a superclass, and Objective C doesn't notice this).

Answer (score 1):

*compiler warns that this Class doesn implement protocol's method* - you haven't implementation for `A` protocol in this class. Add this method to your class:

```
- (void)test{

}
```

Comment: I know that Aimpl doesn't implement protocol's method itself, but it delegates implementation of these methods to another object and I just want suppress warning

Answer (score 1):

If you're forwarding the method from your object to another target, then your object is not implementing the protocol - the target objects are. You need to declare the target objects as implementing the protocol, not your forwarding object.